# Jenkins Kubernetes: Mount subpath of volume

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

As far as i understood, the kubernetes api allows one to mount a subpath of a pvc into the container in the `volumeMounts` spec.

In my example i want to mount the pvc `my-pvc`, but in the subdirectory `/my-subpath` to `/my-mount`.

So the directory `/my-subpath` on `my-pvc` would be mounted in the container under `/my-mount`.

When using Kubernetes normally, this would look like follows if i understood the docs:

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /my-mount
      name: my-pvc
      subPath: "my-subpath"
```

My problem now is, that in the jenkins kubernetes plugin this doesn't seem to be possible.

If i understood the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/) correctly, it seems that it is only possible to mount the root directory, i.e. `/`, of the pvc `my-pvc` to `/my-mount` in the container, since there is no `subPath` option:
[image: Jenkins documentation screenshot]

Is there something i am missing, or is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: I'm not very sure about what you're after but just to clarify, is `my-subpath` a sub-dir of `/my-mount`?

Comment: Usually the volume is mounted from root, i.e. `/`, to `/my-mount` as i understood it. I want to mount `/my-subpath` to `/my-mount`.

Comment: Can you try replacing existing values with the one specified here? `- mountPath: /my-mount/my-subpath` & `subPath: my-subpath`. Also notice that value of `subPath` doesn't contain `/` at the beginning.

Comment: I'm sorry if my description is a bit unclear. I'm not trying to mount to `/my-mount/my-subpath`. The problem is, that the jenkins kubernetes plugin api does not have a `subPath` (see the doc screenshot), or is it just not documented?

Comment: As I understand you want to mount `/pvc/my-subpath` inside your container as `/my-mount`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes @hariK, I belive that this is what OP is trying to do and he also knows how to do it with k8s. The question here is "how to use subpath in jenkins", which apparently doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes that is what i am trying to do and what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by available options of Jenkins Kubernetes plugin ATM. But still, you can achieve this by applying a raw pod template in Kubernetes cloud pod configuration.

Sample output

```
Started by user admin
Replayed #11
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
‘hello-docker-j0rk6’ is offline
Agent hello-docker-j0rk6 is provisioned from template hello-docker
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    run: "hello-docker"
    jenkins: "slave"
    jenkins/label: "hello-docker"
  name: "hello-docker-j0rk6"
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - "cat"
    image: "jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1-alpine"
    name: "hello-docker"
    resources: {}
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/app/logs"
      name: "tmp"
      subPath: "logs"
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
```